# Codeigniter SUM and LEFT JOIN while removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, sum, left-join

I am left joining 4 tables to get SUM of the amount that is present in first table. So far, I've tried many alternatives to get the sum straight, but either it becomes 0 (if I group_by), or duplicates, if I don't use group_by. here is my code:

```
$this->db->select('COALESCE(SUM(cust_ reservation_request.dollar_amount), "0") as total');
        $this->db->join('cust_ reservation_request', 'cust_ reservation_request.id = cust_reservations.rid', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('attendees', 'cust_rid= cust_ reservation_request.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('cust_reservation_cancelled', 'cust_reservation_cancelled.rid = cust_ reservation_request.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->where('cust_ reservation_request.tid IN (5, 6, 7, 8)->where('attendees.status', 1)->where('cust_reservation_cancelled.rid IS NULL');
        $this->db->group_by('cust_reservation_request.id');
        $total = $this->db->get('cust_reservations')->row()->total;
```

I am getting 0 as a value of $total variable, while it should be 288.
However, when I remove `$this->db->group_by('cust_reservation_request.id');` statement, I get duplicate on `attendees.attendees.cust_rid`, which is actually there, $total becomes 498, since there can be more than one attendees for the same rid. I want to remove this duplicate, retaining actual SUM of all the dollar_amount fields.

My tables are:

```
cust_ reservation_request
id   // index, foreign key in rest of other tables
tid
uid
dollar_amount

cust_reservations
id
rid  // related to id in cust_ reservation_request table
reservation_date
pay_token

cust_ reservation_cancelled
id
rid  // related to cust_ reservation_request.id
cancel_date

attendees
id
cust_rid // its the same rid, related to cust_reservation_request.id
status
```

Do you think there can be any safer way to do this, removing duplicates while doing the SUM in a proper way?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to run it without "WHERE cust_reservation_cancelled.rid IS NULL" condition

Comment: Can you run it as SQL query on server without dealing with framework? This way it will be easier to debug

Comment: Hi @IgorM thanks for your reply. I have tried it running on the server, it returns 0 when I add group_by, and returns duplicate rows after using SUM. I have also tried using SELECT * instead of SUM just to see the results returned, and its there I know it returns a row two times.

Comment: Hii @IgorM I tried to run the query without "WHERE cust_reservation_cancelled.rid IS NULL", but the result stays the same.

Comment: run it without COALESCE and without any WHERE condition.

Comment: I only know SQL on the mainframe, so I can only give some directions.
I would use a where exists (select 1 from cust_reservations where rid = just_reservation_request.id) and exists (same for next table) etc.

Comment: Hi @IgorM, I tried to run it without 'COALESCE', again, the result is 0. I didn't run it without where clauses, because if I do, then I'll be getting unwanted results, which is not my objective. Can you suggest any other work around?

Comment: Hi @BenLink thanks for this. can you please show it with a query the way you think it should work?

Comment: Hi Zafar, see my separate answer below with coding.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was: "I think you have problem with your data and the query returns NULL which is converted into 0 by COALESCE", but it wasn't the issue. There was a problem with "status" field in "attendees" table and it was solved mainly by topic starter, so I do not deserve points here

Zafar, happy you managed to solve the problem. Greetings from Israel :)

Comment: As I already explained, I tried to run it without 'COALESCE`, by just putting this in select:  `SELECT SUM(user_reservation_request.dollar_amount) as total` and it didn't work. It sent me 0 again.

Comment: If I've a problem with the data, it shouldn't return some amount, when I remove group_by! It returns some amount, but with a duplicate entry and I can see it when I run it in mySQL.

Comment: @Zafar, you say that you get 0 running the following query SELECT SUM(dollar_amount) FROM cust_ reservation_request... Don't you think there is something wrong with your data type?

Comment: see, if I run this query:`SELECT SUM(cust_ reservation_request.dollar_amount) as total FROM `cust_reservations` LEFT JOIN `cust_ reservation_request` ON `cust_reservation_request`.`id` = `cust_reservations`.`rid` LEFT JOIN `attendees` ON `attendees`.`cust_id` = `cust_ reservation_request`.`id` LEFT JOIN `user_reservation_cancelled` ON `user_reservation_cancelled`.`rid` = `user_reservation_request`.`id` WHERE `cust_ reservation_request`.`tid` IN (6,9,10,16,17) AND `attendees`.`status` = 1` without extra where, it returns 498. so whats wrong with data type?

Comment: As you can see you filter by "user_reservation_request.tid". Probably it filters out awkward records. What is dollar_amount datatype?

Comment: dollar_amount data type is DOUBLE

Comment: run SELECT * FROM cust_ reservation_reques WHERE ISNULL(dollar_value) = 1

Comment: you mean to say I remove all other left joins and just run this simple query to see?

Comment: Sure. This is debug approach

Comment: well it returns nothing, an empty row. no data in it.
`Select *  From cust_reservation_request WHERE ISNULL (dollar_amount) = 1`
and why is that and what does it mean? @IgorM

Comment: It means there is no NULLs. Now run Select SUM(dollar_amount) From cust_reservation_request WHERE tid IN (5, 6, 7, 8) and see what you get

Comment: Hi @IgorM, now it returns the result 521, however, what about other where clauses, because this is something which would be wrong because of the fact that I have some other checks to do, like status, if the attendee has not cancelled reservation, etc etc.. Seems like I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: @Zafar, now start adding your JOINs and WHERE clauses one by one and run the query every time, this way you will find what is wrong

Comment: You are probably missing the point. I did your way. The problem is not the result not returned. The problem is result being returned with duplicate rows added to the same, and thats exactly here: ` LEFT JOIN attendees ON attendees.cust_id = cust_ reservation_request.id`, this returns two rows with same rid. The task is to remove any two duplicate rows and keep only the one before left joining. Wait, can I do it with a subquery?

Comment: @Zafar. in my opinion the cust_ reservation_cancelled table is irrelevant, according to normalization rules. You suppose to have field "cancelled" in cust_ reservation table and this way you know if the reservation is cancelled. Anyway, that your DB. Therefore you shall LEFT join cust_ reservation_cancelled not to cust_ reservation_request,  but to cust_ reservations

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this @IgorM  even if I remove this cust_ reservation_cancelled table, the result still duplicates anyways, there in attendees table. Its very much logical as I understand why is it duplicating. But the problem is: How I keep only distinct rows to be fetched in left join (though tried distinct keyword in query but failed)

Comment: Also, tried sub-query way like this: LEFT JOIN (SELECT `attendees`.`cust_rid`
FROM `attendees`
WHERE `attendees`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `attendees`.`cust_rid`)  attendees ON `attendees`.`cust_rid` = `cust_reservation_request`.`id`
But this too internally checks status =1, it doesn't apply on whole table. Though results are close to what I desire. Only if there is a way, where I can apply status=1 on whole table instead of (attendees) table. Do you see where I'm going?

Comment: @Zafar, you can add WHERE IFNULL(status, 0) = 1 as a global WHERE clause

Comment: Know what? I solved it. Cheers :) its by changing (SELECT attendees.cust_rid) in sub-query to (SELECT *), and then applying where clause  status=1 globally. I'm glad this has been solved. Thank you so much. I can accept your answer, but COALESCE was not the main issue. If you can change answer I'll be happy to mark it as answered :) Thank you @IgorM

Comment: Thank you for this @IgorM, Greetings from UAE :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like...
(translated of how it would be on a mainframe)

it would be something like:

```
    $this->db->select('COALESCE(SUM(cust_ reservation_request.dollar_amount), "0") as total');
            $this->db->where exists (select 1 from cust_reservations where  cust_reservations.rid = cust_ reservation_request.id);
            $this->db->and exists (select 1 from attendees where cust.rid = cust_reservation_request.id); 
            $this->db->and exists (select 1 from cust_ reservation_cancelled where cust_reservation_cancelled.rid = cust_reservation_request.id);
            $this->db->and ('cust_ reservation_request.tid IN (5, 6, 7, 8)->where('attendees.status', 1)->where('cust_reservation_cancelled.rid IS NULL');
            $this->db->group_by('cust_reservation_request.id');
            $total = $this->db->get('cust_reservations')->row()->total;
```

You have to check the syntax and all the () and ' and as I do not know the language except for plain SQL you might have to change 'and exists' in 'where exists' and/or change a where later into an and.

The purpose of this query (in plain SQL) is that you want to  sum the dollar_amount from one table only (cust_ reservation_request) where you want to be sure that there also exists a row in the other tables with the same row_id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @BenLink, however, as already explained by IgorM, I solved it with a subquery and then by globally applying `where attendees.status =1` clause. However, I appreciate your effort. Thank you.